# Where can I see the total compensation (by year?) of each of the employees of the UN?

Tags: united-nations, public-sector-compensation

For example, I read that Ban Ki Moon gets [$227,253](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_much_does_Ban-Ki_Moon_earn_in_one_year?#slide=2). But that is only the base salary. it does not include expenses, over-time, and benefits and bonuses. Is there a website or a spreadsheet that lists how much was each UN employee paid at the year's end including everything? (preferable over the years for comparison).

For example, the state of Massachusetts [reports](http://www.masslive.com/database/statepayroll/) the salaries of all full time employees each year. Does the UN have something similar that lists total compensation?

Comment: Perhaps an annual report or financial report would yield this information...

Comment: Some of this information can be gleaned from a spreadsheet available at http://www.un.org/Depts/OHRM/salaries_allowances/salary.htm

Comment: OK, let me put it this way - the executive management team in large and successful companies get a base salary (lets say 200k). But because of different bonuses and such their salary is bumped to millions. I seen it in their financial reports (DEF14A if traded on the market). How come the UN does not have any reports available for the public to review and compare? I wonder by how much their salary being bumped from those 227k?

Comment: There are approximately 80,000 UN employees in many countries paid in many currencies in only loosely connected sub-bureaucracies with a variety of benefits. Listing all of these is impracticable.

Comment: The top salary is under $300K U.S. There is nothing comparable to the huge bonuses in private sector corporations in the U.N. http://www.pbs.org/wnet/un/life/job.html Your believe otherwise is pure conspiracy theory.

Comment: Why do you give PBS as a source for a UN salary? A public company usually publishes the salary/bonuses/transactions of their top officers. The way the UN is NOT publishing their year-end salaries - that is how a private company acts. This is not a conspiracy theory - it is a PURE question. A question of ethics, and a question - why as multi-billion organization - the UN is not publishing the year-end salaries of their top officers? Billions of people pay their taxes to their governments that sponsor the salaries of these people - therefore - making them public servants.

Comment: I edited your question slightly. What you are calling 'total salary' is called 'total compensation'. Salary is just the dollar amount paid, it would not include benefits.  Similarly, your link to the Massachusetts site is only salaries (benefits paid by the employer are not included, but things like overtime would be).

Comment: If you had actually read the pbs.org link, there is a paragraph that is very telling of the inability to actually answer your question: _If a commercial flight is not available in a specific region, a country's president or national leader will usually provide a private plane. The expenses incurred are then subtracted from the country's UN membership dues._ This means that part of his compensation, at least, is not _paid_ by anyone, but rather reduces the amount owed by the specific country already. How does one count this _perk_?

Comment: @indigochild - the Massachusetts site shows the final dollar amount a person received. Which includes all bonuses etc.

Comment: @CGCampbell - I have read it all. And you are only trying to reason that it "makes sense". It does not. This can be easily reported, but still is not!

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul - I'll see if I can back that up. My suspicion is that will go a long way toward the answer.

Comment: @CGCampbell the costs of business travel are not generally counted in an employee's compensation.

Comment: If you get reimbursed for anything, then they is visible.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul if the SG flies somewhere to represent the UN, the cost of the travel is not counted in the SG's compensation because he is traveling for the benefit of the UN.  The same is true of corporate executives.  If a company spends $100K flying its CEO around the country to visit its satellite offices, that $100K is not included in the CEO's compensation figure.  That is true regardless of whether the company pays for the tickets directly or the CEO pays for them and then gets a reimbursement.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul But this idea that there are some secret millions going to the SG and other top officials is ludicrous.  UN officers' salaries are a matter of public record, as with most government officials.  Aside from the SG, they are on a strict scale based on grade and "step," which is roughly time in grade.  There is a cost-of-living "post adjustment" and various other relatively minor additions such as hazard pay and hardship pay, but these do not apply to the SG.  There is no bonus whatsoever. They don't report compensation because it's completely determined by the civil service scale.

Answer (score 2):

### No, there is no source that lists total compensation for United Nations employees

Previous answers linked to United Nations payroll data. However, that data does not include total compensation, which is what the question asks for.

The U.S. Government Accountability Office performed an [audit](http://www.gao.gov/assets/670/664437.pdf) comparing the compensation of UN employees to US employees. One of their findings is that the UN body which monitors payroll only takes into account salaries - non-wage/salary benefits are excluded entirely from their analyses.

This makes it unlikely that this data is publicly available.

### Most public sources will list salary, rather than total compensation.

Many state governments have publicly accessible *salary* data, similar to the Massachusetts Comptroller's data in the question. However, total compensation data is rarely available to the public.

Salary (or salary and wages) reflects *income*. It includes hourly wages, overtime wages, leave pay, salaries, and other kinds of payment.  It also employees benefits that are paid from the employee's wages or salary. For example, someone may contribute a certain percentage of their paycheck to a retirement account. This would be included in salary and wages.

It does not include taxes or benefits paid by the employer.

Total compensation is an attempt to quantify the total value of pay and benefits to an employee. It includes everything in salary and wages, as well as benefits paid by the employer. For some employers, it may include less tangible benefits as well (such as access to an office daycare center). However, much of that is left to the employer's discretion when calculating.

Let's take a closer look at that data from Massachusett's Comptroller. The original data is [here](http://cthrupayroll.mass.gov/#!/view-data). It is composed of multiple elements: base pay, overtime pay, buyout, and other pay.

The MA Comptroller's Office has a [glossary](http://www.mass.gov/comptroller/cthru/glossarycthru-open-records-transparency-platform.htm) that explains what all of these things are. None of them include benefits. Travel benefits are not income for the employee (but reimbursements for their expenses) and are also not included in income.

### What you are describing is not likely

It's unlikely that you will find the kind of data that you want because payroll doesn't work that way. Below I'll mention some specifics that are within the question:

- **Expenses**: Expense reimbursements are not generally personal income. They are a business expense. The employee is being reimbursed because they paid for legitimate business expenses. This is not going to be included in income data, and probably won't be included in total compensation data either.  When an employee is able to use the employer's assets for personal use (such as by using the company car for personal travel) this is a *taxable fringe benefit* and **is** included as compensation, but no salary or wages.
- **Overtime Pay**: Salaried employees don't earn overtime. Even though they may work more than 40 hours in any given week, they aren't compensated for the additional hours. They are basically paid a set yearly rate. Overtime for hourly employees would be included in both salary and wages as well as total compensation data.
- **Bonuses**: Government employees do not typically earn performance bonuses. The United Nations is not, strictly speaking, a government, but I did not see any mention of performance bonuses on their compensation website.
- **Benefits**: Benefits may be paid by either the employer or the employee. Employee-paid benefits are generally a part of salary and wages. Employer-paid benefits are not, but would be included in total compensation. This is a great simplification because there are a lot of nuances to the IRS rules. However, outside the world of income and payroll taxes, this is how it is generally presented in salary data.

Comment: UN compensation is modeled on civil service, because that's the labor market in which the UN competes for employees.  Hence, your comparison to government employees is apt, and indeed there are no performance bonuses.  There are benefits not common to private-sector jobs such as education grants and income allowances for dependants, as well as rental subsidies for newly relocated staff.  These benefits typically account for a few thousand or tens of thousands of US dollars a year, not millions.

Comment: Also a majority of international staff pay no income tax on their earnings, so IRS rules are not particularly relevant to the question.